# Deploy linux binaries without internet access and without root?

Tags: linux, svn, cx-oracle, binaries

boundaries:

- I have a Linux64 (Redhat 6.8) test-server here which I can access via FTP in our intranet. This server has no access to the internet.
- I want to use an SVN command line client and Python with cx_Oracle and an oracle client on that machine
- I don't have root access.
- I don't have much idea of Linux

I thought I will start with the easiest thing which was SVN in my opinion:
My first guess was, that I could just download the binaries for SVN for Redhat 6 on my windows machine and copy them to the Linux machine using FTP.

But what I found here was "yum install subversion" (which does not work due to missing root and internet access) and a file "subversion_installer_1.9.sh" that I got from WANdisco (but which also needs root and internet access again).

Why is that so complicated? I come from a windows world and I am a little bit disappointed at the moment, because I always thought that stuff like this should work quite easy on LINUX (just copying binaries and you are good to go).
What do I overlook?
How would you do that?

Comment: Is this a programming question? seems like something for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: You cannot install new software without root privileges. If you had root access it wouldn't be trivial to install packages, but doable. 
And iMoses is right, this is not a programming question

Comment: @Bruno9779: Unless `$HOME` is mounted `noexec`, non-privileged users can install software.  It won't make system tasks use their version, but it is perfectly usable from command line and scripts inside their own account.

Answer (score 1):

You can "install" Subversion and Python and cx_Oracle without root access but since you are straying outside of the "normal" approach to things you will find it much more difficult than if you simply followed the "normal" approach. And the "normal" approach is to use a package manager (like yum) which requires root access. The Windows approach is simply different. There have been many arguments over which is "better" but I won't get into that here!

Comment: Ok let's assume that I had root rights (I think I will get the temporary), would I be able to install packages without internet access?
If not, what would be the workaround for that issue again? Let's think about a with the concrete example of a commandline svn-client for linux redhat 6.8 to make this more descriptive

Comment: I got root temporary rights and so I was able to issue 'yum install subversion'. It worked! But I have no idea why. I thought there was no internet access - maybe I was wrong. Or maybe there is some Intranet-repsoitory that was accessible. Also I was able to install an rpm file-for Python's cx_Oracle-module, since it was not available via yum.

Then I learned, that yum is actually something like a smart interface for installing rpms: A package manager which is taking care of package-dependencies on its own (the need to "take care of dependencies" was mentioned by Ben Voigt in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

Installing something on Linux **is** as easy as copying binaries.  The difficulty lies with getting the right binaries to copy.  Unlike Windows where the system API (`kernel32.dll`/`user32.dll`/`gdi32.dll`) is extremely consistent and highly compatible between versions, Linux distributions have multiple system APIs (glibc, newlib, uclibc) and more frequent ABI breakage the *n* in libc.so.*n* changes.

When you download binaries from a repository hosted by your distribution maintainer, you know that they are built to use the same versions of the various dependencies as every other binary on your system.  There's no such guarantee for binaries obtained from the developer, who may use a totally different distribution.

So the common thing for open source projects such as subversion is to obtain an archive of the source code from the developer, unpack it, run `./configure` to customize the makefiles for the system libraries on your system, `make` to build binaries that use your distro's particular flavor of system libraries, and `make install DESTDIR=~/somesoft` to install in any directory you have write access to.

Comment: The first paragraph is exactly what I have thought and what I have experienced so far. It is enough to extend $PATH with some folder containing a binary and after that I can use it just as if it was installed "properly" (at least with my user).
But my problem is rather, that it is not quite understandable for me HOW to download the stuff from my distribution maintainer. If they only provide some scripts themselfes (which again want to download something and require root rights), I cannot copy binaries. I am searching and expecting something like a tar.gz archive containg a svn-client here...

Comment: ..or as you said the "source code from the developer". Where can I find that for Linux Redhat 6.8 for SVN? What is the best way to get that?

Comment: The download page for the source package is here: http://subversion.apache.org/download.cgi  Make sure to read http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALLand have the needed dependencies installed also.

Comment: Thanks. I was to lame to find this. By the way: you might want to edit the hyperlink to the install manual and remove the "and" from it

Comment: Too late to edit the old comment but here's the correct link http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL